# Strategy to cache / persist downloaded images in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, caching, download

My app needs to download about 50 images from an online MySQL database which I'm maintaining. I know I can control the way they're cached using (for example):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aURL] 
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad 
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

But:
1) does using this caching-policy mean the images will truly **forever** remain on the user's device after they've been downloaded the first time? OR,
2) am I better off manually saving them myself to the app's Documents folder (perhaps also concurrently writing a database to there to mirror the one online) to ensure their persistence - that way I can just load them from there (the device's Documents folder) from that point on, on all subsequent runs of the app?

Basically just need recommendation on the best way to persist the images on a user's device after their initial download - so the user always has *something* to look at in case connectivity issues are preventing them from being able to grab whatever new images have been added to the online database.

Any and all advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

NSURLCache uses a memory and a disk cache for downloaded requests. I remember there being issues pre-iOS 5 which led to separate libraries like SDURLCache, but I don't think they're needed anymore.

Even with the disk cache, it may still be cleared out by iOS when space on the device runs short. If you don't want this to happen, you can store the images yourself in the Documents folder... but this situation is what the Caches directory is meant to be for. You download the images, they hang around unless the device runs out of space, in which case they're cleared and re-downloaded as needed. If I was a user of the app, I would prefer that behaviour over permanently taking up disk space for things that can easily be restored from the network.